# Is there any downloader for ubuntu which can resume files?

Tags: wget, downloaders

I just wanted to know if there is any option or if it is a flaw in Ubuntu.

I've seen how to resume file using `wget`, but it is inconvenient because the link to the file has to be typed again.

What to do if I've lost that link or server has changed it?

Comment: As an observation, if the address to what you're downloading changes, no download program can help you resume that download, you'll have to start that one from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

To re-use a command, use your <kbd>↑</kbd> key while on the terminal. Just make sure that the you added the option `-c` to the download command:

```
wget -c http://link/to/download.file
```

As explained by @TheLordofTime in his [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271321/is-there-any-downloader-for-ubuntu-which-can-resume-files#comment340295_271321), if the server changes the address, it is unlikely that any program will adjust itself accordingly.

On the bright side, if the link address has changed, you can run

```
wget -c http://new/link/to/download.file
```

and the download will *continue* getting the partially-downloaded file.

Answer (score 1):

If all you have is the file, without knowing where you got it, then you'd need more than a download manager to resume it. You'd need software that heuristically analyzed the contents of the partial file you have, searched for the file (which would probably be very difficult), downloaded pieces of possible candidates (it wouldn't even start out knowing the proper length for the file, after all, so only by guessing and checking could it figure out what file to download), and eventually download the rest of your file most of the time.

No such utility exists. And no such utility is likely to be developed, because even if you've forgotten a lot, as the person who originally decided to download the file, *you fundamentally know more about where to look for it than anyone else, including any artificial intelligence.*

So, the real-world solution in your situation is for you to search for the file, applying whatever knowledge you have to find what you believe to be the download link for it (or some other download link, if this is a file that is hosted in multiple places).

Answer (score 0):

wget -c, would solve your problem.
If you really want a GUI client, try Fat Rat. I tried this once when I was on a very slow internet connection.